# Is there a way to obtain the min and max of a dcc.Slider object without including them as Inputs in a callback?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

[image]

Basically all the sliders are populated using `dcc.Input`. The program works where input boxes populate the min/max of the slider. The x-axis of the graph that will displayed is based on the last slider that is changed

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('pieces', 'min'),
     Output('pieces', 'max'),
     Output('ups', 'min'),
     Output('ups', 'max'),
     Output('labor', 'min'),
     Output('labor', 'max'),
     Output('production', 'min'),
     Output('production', 'max'),
     Output('setup', 'min'),
     Output('setup', 'max'),
     Output('delivery', 'min'),
     Output('delivery', 'max'),
     Output('foil_markup', 'min'),
     Output('foil_markup', 'max'),
     Output('labor_markup', 'min'),
     Output('labor_markup', 'max'),
     Output('overall_markup', 'min'),
     Output('overall_markup', 'max')],
    [Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks'),
     State('pieces_low', 'value'),
     State('pieces_high', 'value'),
     State('ups_low', 'value'),
     State('ups_high', 'value'),
     State('labor_low', 'value'),
     State('labor_high', 'value'),
     State('production_low', 'value'),
     State('production_high', 'value'),
     State('setup_low', 'value'),
     State('setup_high', 'value'),
     State('delivery_low', 'value'),
     State('delivery_high', 'value'),
     State('foil_markup_low', 'value'),
     State('foil_markup_high', 'value'),
     State('labor_markup_low', 'value'),
     State('labor_markup_high', 'value'),
     State('overall_markup_low', 'value'),
     State('overall_markup_high', 'value')])
def pieces_low_value(n_clicks, pieces_min, pieces_max, ups_min, ups_max, labor_min, labor_max, production_min, production_max,
                     setup_min, setup_max, delivery_min, delivery_max, foil_markup_min, foil_markup_max,
                     labor_markup_min, labor_markup_max, overall_markup_min, overall_markup_max):

    return pieces_min, pieces_max, ups_min, ups_max, labor_min, labor_max, production_min, production_max, \
           setup_min, setup_max, delivery_min, delivery_max, foil_markup_min, foil_markup_max, labor_markup_min, \
           labor_markup_max, overall_markup_min, overall_markup_max
```

Is there a way to obtain the min and max of a `dcc.Slider` object without including both of them as an `Input` to the callback function? Or if it is not possible is there a way to only add the 'min' and 'max' of the slider of interest?

It seems lengthy to actually include an `Input('component_id', 'max')` and `Input('component_id', 'min')` for all the 14 Inputs with the slider values since I will need the 'min' and 'max' of a slider that was last changed which is found by doing `ctx = dash.callback_context`  and  `last_changed = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split(".")[0]`

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure')
    [Input('foil_price', 'value'),
     Input('UOM_foil_length', 'value'),
     Input('UOM_foil_width', 'value'),
     Input('piece_length', 'value'),
     Input('piece_width', 'value'),
     Input('pieces', 'value'),
     Input('ups', 'value'),
     Input('labor', 'value'),
     Input('production', 'value'),
     Input('setup', 'value'),
     Input('delivery', 'value'),
     Input('foil_markup', 'value'),
     Input('labor_markup', 'value'),
     Input('overall_markup', 'value')])
def update_figure(price_per_roll, foil_length, foil_width,
                  piece_length, piece_width, pieces, ups,
                  labor_rate, production_rate, setup,
                  delivery, foil_markup, labor_markup, overall_markup):
    ctx = dash.callback_context
    last_changed = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split(".")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

What are those min and max values based on? You could listen to the data. I know you're more concerned about verbosity, but you could also use `State`, so those values don't trigger the callback.

Comment: Added how the sliders are populated and the graph for more details how it works

Comment: How about, instead of using `dcc.Input`s to feed into the sliders, you just use `dcc.Input`s directly for those values? That would save a lot of callback wiring.

Comment: Was initially planning to have a point move on the line graph as the slider is moved so the incremental effect of the sliders can be seen but it probably can be omitted. But just wondering if there is a simple way like maybe `ctx = dash.callback_context`  to achieve what is needed

Comment: If you want the user to be able to enter all of these values, then I think 9 inputs might be the fewest possible. The callback context will only let you see which input triggered the callback, so that won't help in this case with reducing the number of inputs here.

Comment: Can I see a sample of how it would be done? I was also thinking if it was possible to set the returned values from the functions made in the callback to a global variable this may be another option as well

Comment: Which part? Setting the `dcc.Input` components as `Input`s to a callback?

Comment: Already got it. I found out about `dcc.Store` then I would use it to store a dictionary with the minimum/maximum values of each slider. Then used `dash.callback_context` to determine which slider was last changed and search via key

Comment: Good work! Does that mean you've solved your problem?